# Is there a way to scale uv pupils?

Tags: animation, texturing

Let’s say I have a cartoon character with flat and oddly shaped eyes. In this case I’m using a material with an image texture. I tried animating the pupil by having two images, one with a bigger pupil and one with a smaller pupil, and then switching between the two using a mix shader node. But when I tried animating this, as I figured, the pupil has an effect of fading into the next image, rather than shrinking. How should I fix this?

Comment: Does it need to be a shader? Why don't you use a shape key?

Comment: if at frame 1 the Factor of your Mix shader is at 0 and at frame 2 it is at 1, there should not be any fading

Comment: Well, It's a little tricky because my animation has a pupil that slowly dilates. I can't use a shape key because it's an image texture.